# VBA Match Function on combo box

Tags: vba, combobox, match, lookup

I am trying to get a form to populate data from a sheet using cell `Z` as the lookup reference.

The dropdown on the form showing my list of issue references works. When I select an item from said list to populate the form I get the mismatch error.

Also, my range in `Z` column is a mix of letters and numbers. I did change I to variant but no luck

The `application.match` is returning an error. Any ideas?

> Run Time error '13': Type Mismatch

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inbound Issues")
        Dim i As Integer
        i = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.ComboBox2.Value), sh.Range("Z:Z"), 0)
        Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would help if you can give the error code and description... also, declare `i` as `Long` to avoid potential overflow

Comment: Probably the value in `Me.ComboBox2.Value` cannot be cast into a `Long` with `CLng`? and `Application.Match` does not always return an `Integer` but can return an `Error` so `i` needs to be `Variant`.

Comment: You can avoid the error with `CLng` by testing if `Me.ComboBox2.Value` is a number before attempting the cast. `IsNumeric` is an easy way to quickly check if a string can be converted to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
If Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inbound Issues")
Dim i As Integer
i = Application.Match(VBA.Str(Me.ComboBox2.Value), sh.Range("Z:Z"), 0)
Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
End If
End Sub

Change Clng to Str